# Keyboard's driver seems to be broken

Tags: windows, drivers, keyboard

Few days ago I brought a keyboard from my friend. It'd worked pretty well for 2 days. Apparently, today its driver have been broken.

First, I noticed that all functional keys are not working. Also, some combinations like Ctrl+F5 also are "disabled". Of course, I made sure that Ctrl works properly (Ctrl+alt+del works). And one more thing: with left Shift I'm not able to write T and Y in capital letters (all keys work singly).

It's so weird problem that I've already encountered in the past, but didn't solved it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Drivers don't "break" like that. A hardware problem with the keyboard is much more likely. Find yourself another keyboard.

Comment: Most likely you're right. Have to save money now :C

Answer (score 1):

Keyboards are plug-and-play so they have generic drivers. As comment mentioned these drivers cannot be "broken". I'll second that it is a hardware problem and you need to buy a new keyboard.